# SIPp client to target different hosts

Tags: sipp

I'm creating a SIPp script to generate a few SIP calls. Since I have 4 servers I need to load balance it between all of them. I understand SIPP will resolve the IP from a DNS at the beginning of the execution and use this IP until the scenario is finished.

In order to change that behavior I followed [this suggestion](https://sourceforge.net/p/sipp/mailman/message/34669515/). Basically all I need to do is add this to my uac.xml scenario:

```
<nop>
  <action>
    <setdest host="[field0 file=iplist.csv]" port="5080" protocol="udp" />
  </action>
</nop>
```

However I cannot run the scenario if I suppress the remote host from the command line since it throws: ***Missing remote host parameter. This scenario requires it.***

If I pass the remote host it looks like SIPp ignores the action to set the destination host from the uac.xml script.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load balance from SIPP tool as it requires mandatory host while executing the command. So, you can execute 4 sipp instances with different hosts

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.